# YouTube Embed Tag mute/unmute button, distorted sound

Tags: youtube, wpbakery, embed-tag

The current code is below. I am using Bakery. When I remove the mute tag the sound is distorted like in stereo but instead of real stereo it sounds like double mono. I want it to autoplay with a mute button option with the same audio from the youtube video. Consequently, in bakery when I click "update" to take it live... the layout of the page changes :(

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="YouTube video player" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/wYGgdF-BAx0?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;vq=hd1080&amp;loop=1&amp;rel=0&amp;playlist=wYGgdF-BAx0&amp;controls=2&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Comment: "The current code is below." It seems you forgot to put it...

Comment: <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="YouTube video player" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/wYGgdF-BAx0?autoplay=1&amp;mute=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;vq=hd1080&amp;loop=1&amp;rel=0&amp;playlist=wYGgdF-BAx0&amp;controls=2&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>